# jQuery Tabs - Reference label in current tab?

Tags: jquery, tabs

Fairly new to jQuery and am running into an issue. Going to simplify it for clarity.

Let's say I have 3 tabs, all of which have a button with the same ID and a label with the same ID on them. When a user clicks the button on Tab 1, I want to reference the .html() from the label on Tab 1. When a user clicks the button Tab 2, I want to reference the .html() from the label on Tab 2. Etc, etc.

Is there an easy way to get this, or do I have to have unique IDs for each label/button to do it?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Adding code, here's my index.jsp with the existing tabs:

```
    <div id="tabs">
<ul>
<li>
<a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/your_searches" id="tab1"><span>My Searches</span></a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/public_searches" id="tab2"><span>Public Searches</span></a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/new_search" id="tab3"><span>New Search</span></a>
</li>

<li>
<a href="#tabs-4"  id="tab4">View Article</a>
</li>

</ul>

<div id="tabs-1"></div>
<div id="tabs-2"></div>
<div id="tabs-3"></div>
<div id="tabs-4"> <%@include file="view_article2.jsp"%></div>

</div>

<div id="dialog"                     title="Alert!"></div>
<div id="editDialog"                 title="Alert!"></div>
<div id="editDialogYourSearch"       title="Alert!"></div>
<div id="updateSearchCriteriaDialog" title="Alert!"></div>
```

The jQuery that exists is fairly complex, but adds a tab on a click event using this:

```
$("#" + tabId).load($("#context").val() + '/resources/templates/searchResultsTemplate.html', function () {

var html = $("#" + tabId).html();
$("#" + tabId).html(html.replace(/#tabId#/g, tabId));

var headlnTrEnabled = data.searchResults.searchVO.headlnTrEnabled;
var docTrEnabled    = data.searchResults.searchVO.docTrEnabled;
var languageName    = data.searchResults.searchVO.languageName;

if(headlnTrEnabled == 0) {
        document.getElementById("translated-" + tabId ).disabled=true;
        $("label[for='translated-" + tabId + "']").text("Language translation is unavailable for '" + languageName + "'");
}

// Process the click event on the 'translated' checkbox
processTranslationSupportedCheckboxEvents( tabId );


//alert("new_search queryAndPopulateArticlesSearchResults: before populateResultsPageSearchCriteria");
// Set Search Criteria value in Search Results' hidden fields
populateResultsPageSearchCriteria( data.searchResults, tabId );

// Initialize DataTable
initDataTable( '#articleTable-' + tabId );

// Define double-click method on data rows
initArticleTableDoubleClick( '#articleTable-',
                                                         tabId,
                                                         data.searchResults.searchVO.languageCode,
                                                         "#error" );

// Populate Search Results UI from article list
// var counter = populateSearchResultsTable( tabId, data.searchResults.articleList );
checkHighlight();

$('#searchInfo').html( data.hash );
```

On these added tabs (searchResultsTemplate.html) is where I'd need to reference the labels from a button click. Here's the simplified HTML I have thusfar:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="translated-#tabId#"/><label for="translated-#tabId#">Translate Article Titles</label>

<div align="right"><input type="button" value="Export Excel CSV File.." id="exp-csv" />
<br>
<label id="DownloadLink"></label>
</div>

<input id = "btnSubmit" type="submit" value="Release"/>

<p id="searchTitle-#tabId#" name="searchTitle"></p>

<label id="searchInfo">None</label>
```

The #exp-csv button needs to reference the #searchInfo label on the currently selected tab.

Comment: You need to use DOM traversal to achieve this, but we'd need to see your HTML to show you exactly how.

Comment: ID are by definition unique, and it is invalid to have duplicate id properties in your HTML.. Please post your HTML so we can be sure what have and what you try to accomplish

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your goal with teh html is, but i think you mean something like this:

```
$(".tab").children("button").on("click", function() {
   var genericVariable = $(this).siblings("label").html();
});
```

be warned, this only works on sibling elements (neighboring elements). If the label tag is inside another tag separate from teh button, then you'll have to first traverse up the tag tree with parents().eq(-1) for example, then down to the tag with the label.

Answer (score 0):

Got a little help from someone on the JQuery forums and solved it.

I ended up using:

```
$(this).closest('div').find('.class').html();
```

Traversed out of the element to the nearest div, then went back into the div to find the nearest relevant class file, then returned the HTML.

Thanks for the help, guys.